# Yield return and exception handling

Tags: c#, exception, clr, jit, yield-return

I just had a case with a method using yield return not throwing an ArgumentException which I expected. I have reconstructed the case with the simpliest possible classes here:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var listA = FooA(count: 0);
            Console.WriteLine("A did not throw exception!");
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A threw exception!");
        }

        try
        {
            var listB = FooB(count: 0);
            Console.WriteLine("B did not throw exception!");
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B threw exception!");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> FooA(int count)
    {
        if(count == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Count must be above 0");
        var list = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> FooB(int count)
    {
        if (count == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Count must be above 0");
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A threw exception!
B did not throw exception!
```

Can some one please explain to me why FooB does not throw an exception while FooA does?

Comment: do you have more info?

Comment: FooB will not throw an exception until you start to iterate. This is a common pitfall. It's because of the `yield return`. It will turn the method into a class.

Comment: Typically you split the implementation of the yield method into a separate private method so that the error handling will occur at the call site.

Comment: Because FooB() is never called.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because `FooB` is never even evaluated.

When you call a method, that method is called immediately. When you use `yield` and return an enumerable, that method is only called when something needs to use the value returned, and only a single item at a time; this is the benefit of `yield`ing.

So, if you add something that uses the value

```
try
{
    var listB = FooB(count: 0);
    Console.WriteLine(listB.First()); // use the IEnumerable returned
    Console.WriteLine("B did not throw exception!");
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("B threw exception!");
}
```

You will see your expected result.